# Spock test for java code by mocking jdbc

Tags: unit-testing, spock

i have a class as follows-

```
@Repository
public class TableImpl implements Table{
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource2;
private static List<Object> tableInfo;
public List<Object> getTableInfo() {
    return tableInfo;
}
public void setTableInfo(List<Object> tableInfo) {
    this.tableInfo = tableInfo;
}
public List<String> fetchColumns(BasicDataSource dataSource){
    JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    List<Map<String, Object>> columnMap = jdbctemplate.queryForList("show columns from " + tableInfo.get(0).toString());
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map<String, Object> column: columnMap)
    {
        columns.add(column.get("FIELD").toString());
    }
    return columns;
    }}
```

I wanted to write a test for method fetchColumns here in spock.

This is what I have tried but this is not working--

```
class TableImplSpec extends spock.lang.Specification{

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate=Mock()
DataSource dataSource1=Mock()

def List<Object> tableInfo=[1]
def BasicDataSource dataSourceValue
def BasicDataSource dataSource
def TableImpl obj=new TableImpl(
    dataSource: dataSource1
    )
def Table obj1=new TableImpl(
    dataSource: dataSource1,tableInfo: tableInfo
    )
List<Map<String, Object>> recordsList
    def "fetch columns"()
{
    given:
    TableImpl TableImplMock = Mock()
    def Table obj2=new TableImpl(
        dataSource: dataSource1,tableInfo: tableInfo
        )
     tableInfo.add(0,"promptpaySched")
     tableInfo.add(1,"promptpaySchedID")
     tableInfo.add(2,"name,lastname")
     tableInfo.add(3,1)
     jdbcTemplate.queryForList(_ as String)>> null
    when:
    obj2.fetchColumns(dataSource)
    then:
    1*jdbcTemplate.queryForList(_ as String)
}}
```

the error I am getting is---
IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required. I am totally confused what changes I have to make to my test class.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing tests for code that is interacting with the database, (i.e. reads data from or stores data into it) you might need to adjust your tests to pass actual dataSource (not mocked one).
Else try to mock at Repository level and use it to return expected objects.